# Does monaco editor support delta decoration in minimap?

Tags: monaco-editor

I have simple wholeline delta decorations applied. It works as expected in the editor but not in the `minimap`.  Is there way to have the decorations applied to `minimap` as well?

```
var decorations = editor.deltaDecorations([], [
{ range: new monaco.Range(3,1,5,1000), 
  options: { isWholeLine: true, linesDecorationsClassName: 'myLineDecoration', className: 'myLineDecoration' }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [According to monaco-editor API documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.imodeldecorationoptions.html#minimap):

add `minimap:{position:1}` to the options

```js
var decorations = editor.deltaDecorations([], [ { range: new monaco.Range(3,1,5,1000), options: { 
isWholeLine: true, 
linesDecorationsClassName: 'myLineDecoration', 
className: 'myLineDecoration',
minimap:{ position:1 } 
}}, ]);
```